# Discord.JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined while trying to add roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
   const Discord = require('discord.js');
   const client = new Discord.Client();
   const config = require('./config.json');


   client.once('ready', () => {
       console.log('Ready!');
   });

   client.on('message', message => {
       if (message.content.includes('jail')) {
               let muteUser = message.guild.members.cache.get('832168644230381609');
               let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('845217593970786314');
               let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('845217665906638868');

               muteUser.roles.remove(mainRole).catch(console.error);
               muteUser.roles.add(muteRole).catch(console.error);
               console.log('User muted');
      }
   })

   client.login('');
```

I created this as a test, that is why I have a constant id for the roles and for the user.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined The error
> is for the "muteUser.roles.remove(mainRole).catch(console.error);"

After studying the docs I couldn't find out how can I make it work with the latest version.

Comment: it means that the message does not belong to any guild, thus message.guild is undefined, it's no the issue with the code you've provided per say, but rather with the setup of the rest

Comment: So what should I use to get the roles?

Answer (score 0):

```
let muteUser = await message.guild.members.fetch('832168644230381609');
let mainRole = await message.guild.roles.cache.get('845217593970786314');
let muteRole = await message.guild.roles.cache.get('845217665906638868');

//Muting the user
await muteUser.roles.remove(mainRole).catch(console.error);
await muteUser.roles.add(muteRole).catch(console.error);
```

I should have use fetch and NOT cache for the muteUser one, also I had to resolve my promise with the asyncs